# iOS: Server-Side Objective C implementation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a question regarding implementing a simple server in Objective-C in xCode. I have done a lot of research online before deciding to post the question here.

Basically what me and my coworker would like to archive is as follows:

1.) Allow users to create a simple Profile with profile name, password and a 50 x 50 profile image.

2.) Allow simple communication between users within the App. (we just want to be able to see each other's location on Google map as a pin and send a short message to each other)

So, my point here is that - could some of you, who have had experiences in writing a server in Objective-C in xCode, give me some sample and pointers. It is not a heavy-duty data driven app Requests in JSON-Format between device and server would do (I have experiences in parsing JSON but not generating it).

I have had experiences writing simple Server in Java and Python, but never in Objective-C or within xCode and hope to get some advice from you in doing that in Objective-C within xCode environment. Links, tutorials and / or sample code would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: You could write your server-side portion in any language you wanted as long as it  can parse JSON.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to use Xcode and Objective-C unless you plan on running your server on a Mac server. It still seems silly when languages such as python and ruby can be used to parse the JSON and provide all the processing you need with a quick turnaround time to boot. Each tool has a purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is to look into a Paas (Platform as a service).

http://parse.com has the de-facto iOS SDK for this type of operation. Very helpful sample projects as well.

All of the server engineering is handled by Parse.

Doing what you want from scratch is many tutorials in itself :-)

You'd be looking up setting up a server, apache, mysql, writing the PHP scripts, writing the client code, etc. Parse abstracts all that away. This is all not to mention the headaches with authentication.

EDIT:

Your question is vague and possibly misguided: You can't really "create a server" with XCode. You can write code to deploy on a server in XCode. Say you want to deploy a python webapp, you could write the python code in XCode. However, XCode is only for writing code and is not something you just "build and run" and it works. To have a server-client app, you need

-a computer somewhere (maybe yours)
-an IP address or URL that users can connect to
-a webserver app (like Apache, nginx)
-a database (like mysql)
-an interface between the webserver and the database (python or PHP)

On the server you need

-PHP or python scripts that take incoming requests
-Transform those requests into output and return data

In the client you need

-to make proper requests to the server IP
-encode or serialize data
-decode retrieved data

This is a convoluted process and not something that someone with a little experience can just show you with some sample code.

Comment: Yep. You could save the location coordinates as a PFObject, and another user with a qualifying ACL (access control) could retrieve them. It'd be up to you to implement the Core Location APIs to get your location, and then to display a point based on what you share with Parse

Comment: Every object created with Parse has a strict ACL, meaning that only the user who creates it has read and write privileges to it. You have to explicitly set the ACL on the object before you save it if you wish it to be publicly readable. This is easy, there is a class set up for this task called `PFACL`

Comment: I updated my answer with a quick edit.

Comment: Nope, what you do with parse is create a PFObject with a specific class name, say "MyLocation". Save that PFObject with its own properties, like Latitude and Longitude. Apply a public read ACL to the PFObject, and save it. Other users then issue a PFQuery for the class "MyLocation" and will retrieve PFObjects that have the appropriate ACL. Those users can then get the properties inside the PFObjects (like latitude etc)

Comment: This will be a high level response: YES. Facebook has implemented an engine that is written in C, which is many times faster than the standard methods. However, it took them an entire team of people a very long time to do. I don't think this is something that you can kick out in a weekend.

Comment: I have used a combination of parse.com and a mac application. I store everything on parse.com and the mac application does all the background jobs. The scheduling for the jobs is in the mac application. Back then parse did not have background jobs. I also prefer to write my background jobs in objective c, so i still have not used the background jobs offered by parse.com